# BeamSql tramsformation issues

Tags: apache-beam

I have my below code in which I'm reading a csv file and defining its schema, after that I'm converting it into BeamRecords. and then applying BeamSql to implement PTransforms.

**Code**:

```java
class Clo {
    public  String Outlet;
    public  String CatLib;
    public  String ProdKey;
    public  Date Week;
    public  String SalesComponent;
    public  String DuetoValue;
    public  String PrimaryCausalKey;
    public  Float CausalValue;
    public  Integer ModelIteration;
    public  Integer Published;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
    PCollection<java.lang.String> lines= p.apply(TextIO.read().from("gs://gcpbucket/input/WeeklyDueto.csv"));
    PCollection<Clorox> pojos = lines.apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractObjectsFn()));

    List<java.lang.String> fieldNames = Arrays.asList("Outlet", "CatLib", "ProdKey", "Week", "SalesComponent", "DuetoValue", "PrimaryCausalKey", "CausalValue", "ModelIteration", "Published");
    List<java.lang.Integer> fieldTypes = Arrays.asList(Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.DATE, Types.VARCHAR,Types.VARCHAR,Types.VARCHAR, Types.FLOAT, Types.INTEGER, Types.INTEGER);
    BeamRecordSqlType appType = BeamRecordSqlType.create(fieldNames, fieldTypes);

    PCollection<BeamRecord> apps = pojos.apply(
        ParDo.of(new DoFn<Clo, BeamRecord>() {

            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                BeamRecord br = new BeamRecord(
                    appType, 
                    c.element().Outlet, 
                    c.element().CatLib, 
                    c.element().ProdKey,
                    c.element().Week, 
                    c.element().SalesComponent,
                    c.element().DuetoValue,
                    c.element().PrimaryCausalKey,
                    c.element().CausalValue,
                    c.element().ModelIteration,
                    c.element().Published
                );
                c.output(br);     
            }
        })).setCoder(appType, getRecordCoder()); 

    PCollection<BeamRecord> out = apps.apply(BeamSql.query("select Outlet from PCOLLECTION"));
    out.apply("WriteMyFile", TextIO.write().to("gs://gcpbucket/output/sbc.txt"));
}
```

My questions are:

1. what shall I implement in ExtractObjectsFn() so that the records gets converted into BeamRecords ?
2. How to write the final output to a csv file ?

I have implemented ExtractObjectsFn() as :

```java
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {

    ArrayList<Clo> clx = new ArrayList<Clo>();
    java.lang.String[] strArr = c.element().split("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
        Clo clo = new Clo();
        java.lang.String[] temp = strArr[i].split(",");
        clo.setCatLib(temp[1]);
        clo.setCausalValue(temp[7]);
        clo.setDuetoValue(temp[5]);
        clo.setModelIteration(temp[8]);
        clo.setOutlet(temp[0]);
        clo.setPrimaryCausalKey(temp[6]);
        clo.setProdKey(temp[2]);
        clo.setPublished(temp[9]);
        clo.setSalesComponent(temp[4]);
        clo.setWeek(temp[3]);
        c.output(clo);
        clx.add(clo);
    }   
}
```

Let me know if its done correctly because while executing the code and getting error as `No Coder has been manually specified;  you may do so using .setCoder().`

Comment: The implementation of `processElement()` assumes that it only operates on a single element at a time, not all of the elements from the input source. This is a fundamental feature of transforms in the Beam programming model. In this case, `c.element()` returns a string which is a single CSV line. You don't need to split by the new line delimiter. The for loop is unnecessary since you only process a single element (CSV line) at a time. `c.output(clo)` should be called at the very end of the function. `clx` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1> what shall I implement in ExtractObjectsFn() so that the records gets converted into BeamRecords ?

In the `processElement()` method of `ExtractObjectsFn`, you simply need to convert a CSV line from the input (`String`) to a `Clorox` type. Split the string by the comma delimiter (`,`), which returns an array. Iterate over the array to retrieve the CSV values and construct the `Clorox` object.

> 2> How to write the final output to a csv file ?

Similar process as above. You simply need to apply a new transform that will convert a `BeamRecord` to a CSV line (`String`). Members of the `BeamRecord` can be concatenated into a string (CSV line). After this transform is applied, the `TextIO.Write` transform can be applied to write the CSV line to file.